# timeSpan/Entry/Exit Optimization in Quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat

i have been working on this code for past few days.  I couldn't find any help on this topic.  As the title says, I am trying to find the best times to enter and exit my trades.  To keep the code simple, i need to optimize my rule in quantstrat.  I have the following rule:

```
add.rule(strategy=strat.nm,name='ruleSignal',arguments=list(sigcol='BearReversal',sigval=TRUE,orderqty=100,ordertype='market',orderside='long',replace=FALSE),type='enter',label='enterLong')

#set to True if you want to run this section.  Takes time
optimize <- TRUE
.timespans <- c('T06:00/T10:00', 'T07:00/T11:00', 'T08:00/T12:00','T09:00/T13:00', 'T10:00/T14:00', 'T11:00/T15:00', 'T12:00/T16:00')
if(optimize){
#Entriesa
##optimize entry of Long position
add.distribution(strategy=strat.nm,paramset.label='timespan',
               component.type     ='rule',component.label='enterLong',variable=list(timespan = .timespans),label='Timespan' )

 res <- apply.paramset(strategy=strat.nm,paramset.label='timespan',
                    portfolio.st=strat.nm,account.st=strat.nm,nsamples=0)
```

}

I keep getting error calling combine function: simpleError in fun.  Can someone please help with this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change the component type under add.distribution from "rule" to "enter"